# PHP/SQL, Reduce number of queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am querying a large db in php, and I am not doing it near well enough.
I have the code I need, I simple cannot find a good way to compact these statements.

```
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    (dbinit)
    $query = "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_billing_email' AND meta_value = '$q'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$thing = $row['post_id'];
$querys = "SELECT 'meta_value' FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '$thing' AND meta_key = '_order_number'";
$results = mysql_query($querys);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($results);
$postid = $rows['meta_value'];
$queryss = "SELECT post_id FROM $table WHERE meta_value = $postid AND meta_key = '_order_number'";
$resultss = mysql_query($query);
$rowss = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$order_id = $rowss['post_id'];
(handling)
}
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do these queries, or perhaps have them in one query?

Comment: Use joins, update your driver, use parameterized queries.

Comment: @chris85 so much greatness in so few words - would upvote again if I could.

Comment: **WARNING**: You've created a dangerous [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) by putting `$_GET` data directly in your query. **NEVER** do this. Instead, use the WordPress [prepared statements feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to properly escape all data parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where `$table` comes from.

But this `JOIN` attempt should work:

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
// ... dbinit ...

$query = "SELECT wpp.post_id,
       wpp1.meta_value as orderNumber,
       wpp2.post_id as orderId

    FROM wp_postmeta wpp
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta wpp1 
    ON wpp1.post_id = wpp.post_id 
      AND wpp1.meta_key = '_order_number'
    LEFT JOIN $table wpp2
    ON  wpp2.meta_value = wpp1.meta_value 
      AND wpp2.meta_key = '_order_number'
    WHERE wpp.meta_key = '_billing_email' 
      AND meta_value = '$q'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    (handling)
}
```

As you can see you can get

```
$thing = $row['post_id'];
$order_id = $row['orderId'];
```

inside the loop if needed.

Comment: Sir, you are my god now.

Comment: @Bc1151 don't forget to close the SQL injection.